# Separating the Interface and Implementation in C

Tags: c

In separating the interface from implementation in C, where is the right place to include a header file?

In the interface file (.h file) or in the implementation file (.c file)? Why?

My Sample Code:

console.h

```
#ifndef CONSOLE_H
#define CONSOLE_H

#include <windows.h>

void gotoxy (const WORD x, const WORD y);

void clearScreen();

#endif
```

console.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "console.h"

COORD coord = {0,0};

void gotoxy (const WORD x, const WORD y){
    coord.X = x;
    coord.Y = y;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), coord);
}

void clearScreen(){
    system("cls");
}
```

Comment: Which include directive?

Comment: the #include statement e.g. #include <stdio.h>

Comment: Simple rule, if it isn't necessary to make the .h file compile, don't #include it in the header file..

Comment: Is it a bad practice to put the #include statement in both files?

Comment: My rule: includes that are required in virtually all implementation files (because they provide basic services) go to a common header. Includes that are used sporadically, directly in the source files (and only those that are actually required).

Comment: Where possible, try not to include massive header files like <windows.h> or if you really have to, **#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN** before including it

Comment: Also, in console.c, #include console.h as the very first include file.  That will ensure that it has no other dependencies and can be included anywhere in any other file that uses it.

Comment: @cup The #ifdef at the top of the file ensure that you can include it multiple times without redefinition. Furthermore, header files are used primarily for semantics checks during compilation, and as such don't add to the size of the object files or finished executable.

Comment: @CDahn agreed, but if it is included in multiple source files, it does add to the build times.  In an extreme case that I worked on 15 years ago, just taking the big header out reduced the build time from 23 hours to 80 minutes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some principles:

1. **An unnecessarily included header only adds to the compilation time.**
   This may sound ignorable, and it generally is, but if you get into the habit of including too much, it can become an issue.

   Imagine you have a general header for your project, that includes all other project headers and all the system headers they may need. So any .c file only needs to include this one header and be done with it. This is convenient. However, apart from prolonging the compilation of each .c file a bit, it also guarantees that you have to recompile *the entire project* every time you change a single header. And that will significantly slow down your modify-compile-test cycle.
2. **You must avoid creating circular include dependencies.**
   If you do create a circular include, you are in for trouble. So, best avoid including anything unnecessary: the less you include, the less headers can trigger circular includes. Sometimes you may be required to insert a forward declaration instead of an include.
3. **A .c file must include its .h file.**
   If you fail to do this, the function signatures in the .c file won't be checked against the declarations in the .h file, and madness will follow.

   The problem with this principle is, that your .c file may compile fine without the include if the .h file does not define a type that is needed by the implementation. Nevertheless, the include must be there to prevent signature mismatches.

So, apart from point 3, it is prudent to only include headers that are absolutely needed, and only in the file that actually needs it. Personally, I frequently only include a header *after* I get a compiler error telling me that something is missing.

Comment: Can you give an example of circular include dependency?

Comment: Say, you have two types of objects that have to work together (each must maintain a pointer to the other), and a header for each type. Each header needs to know about the type defined in the other, so each would like to include the other. But if both do, you get either an infinite recursion, or, assuming correct include guards, one header will end up being inserted before the other, triggering a compiler error. In such cases, you must do at least one forward declaration instead of an include.

Answer (score 2):

Include directives should always be included in the file that needs them, or to make reading and understanding your code easier.

In your example, you include windows.h inside console.h. For such a common header file, it'd be fine to leave it in console.h only. However, if you were using another library that you'd written, and was not already widely adopted, it would be wise to include it in both files to prevent future developers from having to hunt through header files searching for the one which provided functionality seen in console.c.

Answer (score 1):

There are only two changes to your setup I would make. I would include all headers in the header file except for the `console.h` header which is necessary to include the header. Second, when you `#define CONSOLE_H  1`, give it a value `1` is fine. I just prevents an uninitialized tag. Looks good.

console.h

```
#ifndef CONSOLE_H
#define CONSOLE_H  1

#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void gotoxy (const WORD x, const WORD y);

void clearScreen();

#endif
```

console.c

```
#include "console.h"

COORD coord = {0,0};

void gotoxy (const WORD x, const WORD y){
    coord.X = x;
    coord.Y = y;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), coord);
}

void clearScreen(){
    system("cls");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Like it was already mentioned in comments and other answers - includes should be in the file that needs them.

However, for complex/large projects, I'd recommend to design the interfaces such that they require only handlers/references to actual data instead of actual data. This allows usage of forward declarations in header files and actual includes in the implementation files. The reason for this is avoidance of **tight coupling**. Tight [Coupling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_%28computer_programming%29) often leads to very problematic behavior, forcing to include headers that aren't directly needed (and even creating circular dependencies, resulting in compilation failures and need for extensive changes!), increasing compilation time and harming such SW quality attributes as modularity, maintainability and scalability.

That said, there are common headers (usually part of the environment you're using) that are needed in most situations (e.g., stdio.h, windows.h etc.) - including these won't hurt the SW quality although the compilation time might still increase. One way to deal with this is to use [Precompiled headers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precompiled_header).